# Cannot insert sdo_geometry with more than 500 vertices

Tags: c#, oracle11g, odp.net, esri, oracle-spatial

I have the following table

`CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (MYID VARCHAR2(5), MYGEOM MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY );`

AND the sql statement below:

`INSERT INTO MYTABLE (MYID,MYGEOM) VALUES
    ( 255, SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 2554, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1),
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-34.921816571,-8.00119170599993,
    ...,-34.921816571,-8.00119170599993)));`

Even after read several articles about possible solutions, I couldn't find out how to insert this sdo_geometry object.
The Oracle complains with this message:
**ORA-00939 - "too many arguments for funcion"**

I know that it's not possible to insert more then 999 values at once.
I tried stored procedure solutions, but I'm not Oracle expert, and maybe I missed something.
Could someone give me an example of code in c# or plsql ( or the both ) with or without stored procedure, to insert that row?

I'm using Oracle 11g, OracleDotNetProvider v 12.1.400 on VS2015 AND my source of spatial data comes from an external json ( so, no database-to-database ) and I can only use solutions using this provider, without datafiles or direct database handling.
I'm using SQLDeveloper to test the queries.

Please, don't point me articles if you are not sure that works with this row/value

Comment: The query has more than 500 vertices, and I couldn't paste here, because StackOverflow blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found an effective solution. Here: [Constructing large sdo_geometry objects in Sql Developer and SqlPlus. Pls-00306 Error](http://spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/331/pls-00306-wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to-sdo_geometry)

Comment: can you please provide more details? I tried to use stored procedure and then invoke in plsql way,  did not have luck. still fails at 500+ coordinates

Answer (score 1):

The limitation you see is old. It is based on the idea that no-one would ever write a function that would have more than 1000 parameters (actually 999 input parameters and 1 return value).

However with the advent of multi-valued attributes (VARRAYs) and objects, this is no longer true. In particular for spatial types, the SDO_ORDINATE attribute is really an object type (implemented as a VARRAY) and the reference to SDO_ORDINATE is the constructor of that object type. Its input can be an array (if used in some programming language) or a list of numbers, each one being considered a parameter to a function - hence the limit to 999 numbers).

That happens only if you hard-code the numbers in your SQL statement. But that is a bad practice generally. The better practice is to use bind variables, and object types are no exception. The proper way is to construct an array with the coordinates you want to insert and pass those to the insert statement. Or construct the entire SDO_GEOMETRY object as a bind variable.

And of course, the very idea of constructing a complex geometry entirely manually by hardcoding the coordinates is absurd. That shape will either be loaded from a file (and a loading tool will take care of that), or capture by someone drawing a shape over a map - and then your GIS/capture tool will pass the coordinates to your application for insertion into your database.

In other words, that limitation to 999 attributes / numbers is rarely seen in real life. When it does, it reflects misunderstandings on how those things work.